# Animate Slider with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I'm buidling a Drupal website. On the homepage I've outputted three images in a row. Those three images are different news articles. I want it to start with a red transparant overlay on second and third image. After 5 seconds I want the first and third image to have that overlay and after another 5 seconds I want the first and second image to have the overlay. So every 5 seconds the next image is 'highlighted' without an overlay.

I've searched a lot on here an the internet, I tried stuff with CSS Keyframes, but I can't manage to let it work. Here's an image example how it should start:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ciWp.jpg

Who can help me out? Thanks in advance!

PS: I used OWL Slider to output the images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `background:url(...)`, and then use the `:before` pseudo element on the div. You'd have to play around with timing (of delays as well), but something like this would work:

```css
div{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
  background-size:100% 100%;
  }
div:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-animation: showw 6s infinite;
  animation: showw 6s infinite;
  }

div:nth-child(2):before{
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  }

div:nth-child(3):before{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  }

@-webkit-keyframes showw{
  0%, 30% {background:rgba(255,0,0,0);}
  35%, 60% {background:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);}
  }
@keyframes showw{
  0%, 30% {background:rgba(255,0,0,0);}
  35%, 60% {background:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);}
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm! How can I set a smooth transition? The red blocks are now changing in a split second, I would like them to fade in and out a little bit. I tried working with CSS transitions like you do for a hover, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: @PetervanRemmen: I've edited for a slight transition by altering the keyframes. Playing about with them should give you an idea of how that's working.

Comment: It's like magic! You really helped me out here and I'm starting to get the keyframes better. Thanks! I have one more question: is it possible to stop keyframes from working on a smartphone in a media query or something like that?

Comment: in your media query use something like animation: none; (with prefixes)